# Magento 2 Remove Javascript from requirejs in child theme

Tags: magento2, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

We're extending the `Magento_Blank` theme to create our own child theme. `Magento_Blank` includes some `js` via `require_js` theme.js and responsive.js` which are not required.

I cannot figure out how to remove these from my child theme. I tried creating a blank `requirejs-config.js` in `Magento_Theme` which didn't seem to work.

How can I do this ? I'd rather not create blank files for each as this will mean we have network requests which have no purpose.

Comment: try like this in <head> tag <remove src="Magento_Catalog::js/catalog-add-to-cart.js" /> in your default.xml Magento_Theme folder

Comment: Please check it, this may help you.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html#disable_default_js